# Need PullToRefershListView functionality with expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, pull-to-refresh

Actually I have to apply two functionality 1st one is pull to refresh view and 2nd one is animated expandable child in list view.

When i click on a button of list item then a layout comes from top to bottom and again when i click on this button this layout goes to bottom to top. I can see this functionality in ExpanableCells  project.

And I also need that when user scroll list view then my list would refreshed.

For both of functionality I have two projects PullToRefreshView library and ExpandableCells Project but both the developer apply ListView in different way that's I am not able to use both of them. I can only use on of them.

Anyone apply both of them please help me. Or I have to implement both of them from base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SwipeRefreshlayout which is provided by the android and you need support library : android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Also you can write the your xml layout like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.expandablelistviewwithpultoreferesh.MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in MainActivity,

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
```

make you activity implement the OnRefreshListener and add unimplemented methods i.e.

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Source(tutorial) for implementation : 
Expandable ListView:- 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

SwipeRefreshlayout:-
http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

note: make sure you have an updated Android SDK also  if you want an animated Expandable listView , you can try this library https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView which simply extends the ExpandableListview

Comment: @Sachine, I have to do similar as in iPhone I have no other choice but I found a way to do this by inter polator. I will update soon.